# yum update if installed, otherwise install

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, update, packages

Is there a command to do just that:
if a package is already installed, update it, otherwise install the latest version

For now I'm doing two commands:

```
yum install mypackage
yum update mypackage
```

Maybe there's a more efficient way?

Answer (score 7):

At least for me, `yum` is bright enough that if I tell it to install something which is already installed, and for which an update is available, it will just apply the update instead.  E.g.:

```
[root@risby ~]# rpm -qa|grep openvpn
openvpn-2.2.2-7.fc17.x86_64
```

openvpn is installed.

```
[root@risby ~]# yum update
[...]
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openvpn.x86_64 0:2.2.2-7.fc17 will be updated
---> Package openvpn.x86_64 0:2.3.1-2.fc17 will be an update
```

An update is available.

```
[root@risby ~]# yum install openvpn
[...]
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openvpn.x86_64 0:2.2.2-7.fc17 will be updated
---> Package openvpn.x86_64 0:2.3.1-2.fc17 will be an update
```

`yum install` does the right thing anyway.  yum version is 3.4.3, by the way.

Comment: I observed this behavior of yum a few times, but since I haven't found it documented anywhere, I wonder if I can rely on it.

Comment: Using yum 3.2.29-60 here and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @proteantech Try something a little less ancient. That version of yum is from 2009; while this question and yum version is from 2013.